# How to pass an object with encapsulation (private properties) to another tab through localStorage?

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage, encapsulation

If I try to pass an instance of it to another tab through localStorage where I need to use JSON.stringify, the object logically becomes empty. Is there any way to pass it without saving the private properties in a different way by using getters? Can I somehow stringify the instance in a different way and pass it without losing it original character?

I have the following class definition:

```
class User {
  constructor(username, password, email) {
    let _username = '';
    let _password = '';
    let _email = '';

    this.setUsername = username => {
      if (!username) {
        throw new Error("Benutzername darf nicht leer sein!");
      }
      _username = username;
    };
    this.getUsername = () => _username;

    this.setPassword = password => {
      if (!password) {
        throw new Error("Passwort darf nicht leer sein!");
      }
      _password = password;
    };
    this.getPassword = () => _password;

    this.setEmail = email => {
      if (!email) {
        throw new Error("E-Mail-Adresse darf nicht leer sein!");
      }
      _email = email;;
    }
    this.getEmail = () => _email;

    this.setUsername(username || '');
    this.setPassword(password || '');
    this.setEmail(email || '');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to save it to localStorage, something like this:

```
saveToLocal() {
  localStorage.setItem(this._email, JSON.stringify(
    { this._email, this._username, this._password }
  ));
}
```

And then you can retrieve it from localStorage by using:

```
localStorage.getItem(<email>) || {};
```